# Sorting text file by number in python

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a text file  in a numbered order (Highest values shown first), each value is on a new line. Below is a sample of my data stored in a .txt file which is written to every time a user completes a quiz.

> 'Anton v1'0 'Antonv2'0 'Henry'0 'Joe'0 'Berty'0 'Lee'0 'Antttton'1
>   'Anton22'0

So far I have found how to order them by alphabetical order, which solves part of my problem:

```
with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in sorted(r):
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Do you have control over the file format? Because that format is kind of nasty. If you add a comma, ie `"Anton v1",0`, and you can use the `csv` moduled to read/write it easily.

Comment: I have added a comma, how would I use the CSV method? :-) if studentclass == ("3"):
    f2 = open("class3.txt", "a")
    f2.write( repr(q) + ","+repr(score) + '\n' )

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should select it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import re
import operator

def to_number(s):
    try:
        return int(re.sub(r'^\s*(\d+)[^0-9].*$', r'\1', s))
    except ValueError:
        return 10**10

data = []

with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        data.append((to_number(line), line))        

for x in sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print(x[1], end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use `csv` module, and how to sort your data using a custom key.

First, a couple of utility functions:

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename, row_formats=None, **csvopts):
    """
    Read from a Comma Separated Value file;
    returns a list of rows, where each row is a list of cell-values
    """
    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        rd = csv.reader(csvfile, **csvopts)
        if row_formats:
            data = [[fmt(cell) for fmt,cell in zip(row_formats, row)] for row in rd]
        else:
            data = list(rd)
    return data

def write_csv(filename, data, **csvopts):
    """
    Write to a Comma Separated Value file;
    `data` is an iterable of rows, where each row is an iterable of cell values
    """
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        wt = csv.writer(csvfile, **csvopts)
        wt.writerows(data)
```

now, we can load your data file,

```
data = read_csv("class3.txt", (str, int))
```

which gives us

```
data = [
    ['Anton v1', 0],
    ['Antonv2',  0],
    ['Henry',    0],
    ['Joe',      0],
    ['Berty',    0],
    ['Lee',      0],
    ['Antttton', 1],
    ['Anton22',  0]
]
```

sort it,

```
def sort_key(row):
    """
    This will sort by descending score then by ascending name
    """
    return -row[1], row[0]

data.sort(key=sort_key)
```

which results in

```
data = [
    ['Antttton', 1],
    ['Anton v1', 0],
    ['Anton22',  0],
    ['Antonv2',  0],
    ['Berty',    0],
    ['Henry',    0],
    ['Joe',      0],
    ['Lee',      0]
]
```

and you can write it back to file like

```
write_csv("class3.txt", data)
```

while produces

```
Antttton,1
Anton v1,0
Anton22,0
Antonv2,0
Berty,0
Henry,0
Joe,0
Lee,0
```